# turtlebot with one or two laptops

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and Linux. Interested in getting a turtlebot.
From turtlebot's website, it seems it already has a laptop directly connected to the turtlebot via a USB calbe.

here is my questions. How is the turtlebot typically used?

a) Do I need to have another laptop/desktop that is connected to the laptop on turtlebot via network, so that instructions can be transmitted from the laptop/desktop to the laptop on the turtlebot via the network?

b) or can  I just use the laptop on top of the turtlebot, if I feel it is not inconvenient to unplug the laptop from turtlebot, write my program on the laptop, and then plug the laptop to the turtlebot?

Thank you.

Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44765/turtlebot-with-one-or-two-laptops/) by [Jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3171/jackie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have used many, many TurtleBots. :)

When we are doing more basic development work with the TurtleBot (parameter tweaking, minor changes, running long-duration tests), the onboard netbook is sufficient. Whenever we need to do more detailed development work, a second computer is recommended. Two main reasons for this:

1. Display/graphics: Properly displaying all of the data that the robot can provide alongside your source code is done best with a good monitor (or monitors).
2. Comfort. Long periods of programming at knee height is uncomfortable. You can avoid this by unplugging the robot/uncoiling the cables, but it's nice to be able to rapidly iterate on coding and live tests without having to worry about putting the cables/netbook back together.

As I said, once we're generally happy with the results and are just tweaking things, we'll usually do so on the netbook.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no direct experience working with turtlebots, so judge my advice accordingly.

But, I suspect you will find it much more convenient to use a separate (perhaps more powerful) system for development. That could be either a laptop or a desktop.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2